# Using invalid character "²" for squared. Extend Julia syntax with custom operators

Tags: julia

In my equations we have many expressions with a^2, and so on. I would like to map "²" to ^2, to obtain something like that:

```
julia> a² == a^2

true
```

The above is not however a legal code in Julia. Any idea on how could I implement it ?

Comment: Unless Julia allows for addition of new syntactic elements in the language from programs themselves, then this is really a feature-request you should bring up with the Julia team instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you don't know that Julia has Lisp like [**syntactic** macros](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#man-macros-1)? that literally *allows the addition of new **syntactic** elements in the language form programs themselves*. Yet you put it on hold? Please un-hold this question, I have an answer.

Comment: @SalchiPapa I coted to close it as to broad, because it is. This is not a discussion forum, we're not really here to answer questions such as "Isn't this neat, what do you think?" (which basically is what this is). If the question was "I like this feature, and I have tried to do it this and that way, but they didn't work because of those the these problems. Is thera a way to do it or to fix my attempts?" not that would be a pretty good question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh ok, got it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: varantir, as I mentioned in the other comment Julia has lisp like syntactic macros, so you could change (within the macro) what does `a²` means. However you should first take into account why would you want to do this in the first place. Is it purely for having a syntax that looks closer to math (consider math readability vs programming readability)? Is it just to save a few keyboard strokes (however a² takes `a\^²<TAB>` so not much strokes saved in the end)? You would have to use something like `@foo a²` which could transform it to `a^2` for you, but notice that `a²` is already a valid...

Comment: ... variable identifier. How would you manage those edge cases? Having to prepend the macro name selectively before the expression would get hectic in no time and looks uglier in the end IMHO. Also notice that `²` is not a valid variable identifier all by itself, that is, since `²` is *kinda* numeric in Unicode category, even if it does not have any kind of numeric value attached like the literal `2` and you can not start a variable identifier with a number, even if it's just a number like symbol, not an actual number :(

Comment: If you manage to come up with a valid identifier you like, ie. `⁺²`, then, instead of *macros* you could use *multiple dispatch* and *multiplication by juxtaposition* to emulate post-fix notation for function calls (`(x)⁺²`, `(A)ᵀ`, see: [JuliaLang/julia/#21037](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21037#issuecomment-343533418)). Notice that the parenthesis are mandatory in this case, because `Aᵀ` for example is another valid identifier, and also `ᵀ` is still a valid symbol that can be used in other identifiers, this way there is no need to special case the syntax inside of a macro.

Comment: So you could do this: `⁺²(x) = x^2; Base.:*(x, f::typeof(⁺²)) = f(x); a, b = 5, rand(5, 5); (a)⁺², (b)⁺²` But now you have to type `(a)\^+<TAB>\^2<TAB>` If you are thinking in a Domain Specific Language, there are better ways to achieve this syntax surgar, like using your own parser, ie. [LispSyntax.jl](https://github.com/swadey/LispSyntax.jl/blob/master/src/parser.jl), that uses [ParserCombinator.jl](https://github.com/andrewcooke/ParserCombinator.jl) but see [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/writing-a-parser-in-julia/13769) for more up to date examples of libraries and ideas . :)

Comment: I rephrased the original OP question. I honestly don't see any reason while this question should be on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample macro `@hoo` that does what you requested in a simplified scenario (since the code is long I will start with usage).

```
julia> x=5
5

julia> @hoo 3x² + 4x³
575

julia> @macroexpand @hoo 2x³+3x²
:(2 * Main.x ^ 3 + 3 * Main.x ^ 2)
```

Now, let us see the macro code:

```
const charsdict=Dict(Symbol.(split("¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹","")) .=> 1:9)
const charsre = Regex("[$(join(String.(keys(charsdict))))]")

function proc_expr(e::Expr)
    for i=1:length(e.args)
       el = e.args[i]
       typeof(el) == Expr && proc_expr(el)
       if typeof(el) == Symbol
            mm = match(charsre, String(el))
            if mm != nothing
                a1 = Symbol(String(el)[1:(mm.offset-1)])
                a2 = charsdict[Symbol(mm.match)]
                e.args[i] = :($a1^$a2)
            end
       end
    end
end

macro hoo(expr)
   typeof(expr) != Expr && return expr
   proc_expr(expr)
   expr
end
```

Of course it would be quite easy to expand this concept into "pure-math" library for Julia.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any reasonable way of doing this.

When parsing your input, Julia makes no real difference between the unicode character `²` and any other characters you might use in a variable name. Attempting to make this into an operator would be similar to trying to make the suffix `square` into an operator

```
julia> asquare == a^2
```

The `a` and the `²` are not parsed as two separate things, just like the `a` and the `square` in `asquare` would not be.

`a^2`, on the other hand, is parsed as three separate things. This is because `^` is not a valid character for a variable name and it is therefore parsed as an operator instead.

Comment: you could do: `square(x) = x^2; Base.:*(x, f::typeof(square)) = f(x); a, b = 5, rand(5, 5); (a)square == square(a), square(b) == (b)square # (true, true)` and still be able to do `square(a), square(b)` like usual, so `(A)ᵀ` is legal, but `(a)²` is not, because `²` is part of the rule of number like characters are ilegal at the start or on their own as variable identifiers, just as normal numbers, ie.: `2 = 3` and `² = 3` are both invalid syntax. :(